# Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match R

Tags: r

I am trying to do some feature engineering on test and train data. I am well versed with python but new to R.

```
#Row binding train & test set for feature engineering
train_test = rbind(train, test)
```

It seems that my train and test data have different number of columns. How to resolve this so that the only columns which are common in both dataframes stay?

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the common columns:

```
common_cols <- intersect(colnames(train), colnames(test))
```

Now perform the rbind

```
train_test=rbind(subset(train, select = common_cols), 
  subset(test, select = common_cols))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would find out what the column names are for both data frames, take their intersection (common names), and selecting those columns from both data frames:

```
train_names <- colnames(train)
test_names <- colnames(test)
common_names <- intersect(train_names, test_names)

train_test <- rbind(train[common_names], test[common_names])
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to use the merge() or inner_join() functions. rbind() *only* works when the number of columns are the same and when the columns have the same name.

https://www.programmingr.com/examples/r-dataframe/merge-data-frames/
https://www.programmingr.com/tutorial/inner-join-in-r/