# Creating A New Calculated Category Within A Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, categories, data-manipulation, calculated-columns

Suppose I have a data frame similar to this, only with 1000's of observations:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B',
                           'B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D'),
                 Values=c('5','7','9','0','8','4','5','2','1','3','6','3','1','3','5'))
```

What I want to do is add a new calculated group to the data frame based on values in a group that already exists in the data frame **without replacing** the original group's values. For example, lets say I want to retain group D, but create a new group with all of group D's values +2.

An example of the resulting dataframe I would like is the following:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B',
                           'B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D'
                           ,'Dadjusted','Dadjusted','Dadjusted','Dadjusted','Dadjusted'),
                 Values=c('5','7','9','0','8','4','5','2','1','3','6','3','1','3','5',
                          '8','5','3','5','7'))
```

I have tried using ifelse statements like the following:

```
   df$adjustedvalues<-ifelse(Group=='D', df$Values+2, df$Values)
```

but this approach results in data frames that look like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B',
                           'B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D'),
                 Values=c('5','7','9','0','8','4','5','2','1','3','6','3','1','3','5')
                 adjustedvalues=c('5','7','9','0','8','4','5','2','1','3','8','5','3','5','7')
```

Which is less than ideal for my purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible base R option:

```
rbind(df, data.frame(Group = "Dadjusted", 
                     Values = as.integer(df$Values)[df$Group == "D"]+2))
```

**Output**

```
       Group Values
1          A      5
2          A      7
3          A      9
4          B      0
5          B      8
6          B      4
7          B      5
8          C      2
9          C      1
10         C      3
11         D      6
12         D      3
13         D      1
14         D      3
15         D      5
16 Dadjusted      8
17 Dadjusted      5
18 Dadjusted      3
19 Dadjusted      5
20 Dadjusted      7
```

Comment: This ended up being the approach that worked easiest. In my initial statement I forgot to mention that the original data frame contains many more columns than the adjustment dataframe. Fixing that involved making use of intersect and subset as part of the rbind, as shown in this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120906/error-in-rbinddeparse-level-numbers-of-columns-of-arguments-do-not-matc?msclkid=5a664ab5c5a911ec804346c1bbc1932b

Answer (score 2):

You could use `bind_rows`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% 
            filter(Group == "D") %>%
            mutate(Values = as.character(as.numeric(Values) + 2),
                   Group = "Dadjusted"))
#>        Group Values
#> 1          A      5
#> 2          A      7
#> 3          A      9
#> 4          B      0
#> 5          B      8
#> 6          B      4
#> 7          B      5
#> 8          C      2
#> 9          C      1
#> 10         C      3
#> 11         D      6
#> 12         D      3
#> 13         D      1
#> 14         D      3
#> 15         D      5
#> 16 Dadjusted      8
#> 17 Dadjusted      5
#> 18 Dadjusted      3
#> 19 Dadjusted      5
#> 20 Dadjusted      7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
Also a `dplyr` solution similar to @Allan Cameron ones but not as elegant:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  filter(Group=="D") %>% 
  mutate(Group = "Dadjusted",
         Values = Values + 2) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              type.convert(as.is = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(Group)
```

```
         Group Values
1          A      5
2          A      7
3          A      9
4          B      0
5          B      8
6          B      4
7          B      5
8          C      2
9          C      1
10         C      3
11         D      6
12         D      3
13         D      1
14         D      3
15         D      5
16 Dadjusted      8
17 Dadjusted      5
18 Dadjusted      3
19 Dadjusted      5
20 Dadjusted      7
```